# I am having trouble using the map function over an array. It only works on the first index property of an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

journalObj is undefined at the 5th line of code but works on the second and third.

journalObj.journalText is the reference for the first index property of the array and it works fine, but journalObj.journalImage is causing an Uncaught Reference Error. What is the issue here?

```
`journalListArr.map(journalObj => 
        // console.log(journalObj.journalText)
        journalEntryTextEl.innerHTML = journalObj.journalText,
        journalEntryListItemEl.appendChild(journalEntryTextEl),
        journalEntryImageEl = journalObj.journalImage,
        journalEntryImageEl.setAttribute("src", journalObj.journalImageURL),
        journalEntryListItemEl.appendChild(journalEntryImageEl),
        journalListEl.appendChild(journalEntryListItemEl)
        )`
```

Comment: please provide further details: console output of any errors, the journalListArry content etc...

Comment: By not using `{}` in your callback, you're implying a return. I wouldn't recommend using chained assignment like that either, it ruins any semblance of readability, and causes issues in debugging like you're experiencing now.

Comment: [{…}]
0
: 
journalImage
: 
img
journalImageURL
: 
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/169647/pexels-photo-169647.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-peng-liu-169647.jpg&fm=jpg"
journalText
: 
"asdf"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)main.js:68 Uncaught ReferenceError: journalObj is not defined
    at renderJournalList (main.js:68:35)
    at HTMLButtonElement.handleSubmitJournalEntry (main.js:75:5)

Comment: I used a for loop instead and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewAbebe You can get rid from this error by using `Optional chaining (?.)` operator as looks like some of these properties are missing from your array of objects. You can try like this `journalObj?.journalImage`